# 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, This issue arrives everytime when i try to run Forever Node Module

Tags: javascript, express, node-modules, forever

I'm using this command- forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 ./bin/www

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command - This error appears in logs everytime(C:\Users\bbls.forever)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this command after putting path ./bin/www into quotes e.g. "./bin/www". so that it can handle spaces in the path.

Comment: This is not working getting the same error

Comment: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1